# Converting `UInt16` to byte array

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation, bitconverter

How to convert an `UInt16` valu to a byte array of size 2

I found some code in MSDN but I am not sure if it is ok to use in my case:

```
// Convert a ushort argument to a byte array and display it. 
public static void GetBytesUInt16( ushort argument )
{
    byte[ ] byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes( argument );
    Console.WriteLine( formatter, argument, 
        BitConverter.ToString( byteArray ) );
}
```

What I have is `UInt16` ... is it ok to just cast it to `ushort` and use the code above?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UInt16 and ushort are the same datatypes so yes

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbf1574z(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Don't you mean that *a cast is not needed*?

Comment: the question was "is it ok to just cast it to ushort and use the code above?!" ... the answer is yes

Comment: A better answer is "Casting is foolish and unnecessary, it already is the right type, just use the code already."

Comment: indeed - it's redundant. Also surprised the op didn't just try it before posting here. Surely a JDI if I ever saw one

Comment: link is broken, answer not related question